# Data-driven line thickness in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4?

Tags: symbology, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to render a line featurelayer and would like to set the thickness (width) of lines based on one of the attributes, which is a continuous value between 0-1; for example for value of zero the thickness would be 1, for the value of 1 the thickness would be 10, and other values between 0-1 would be proportionally assigned a thickness (width) between 1 to 10. I am looking at [this example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=visualization-vv-size) from ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.2 in which the size of circles are determined based on an attribute.

Could we do a similar thing for lines' thickness?

In visualvariables what value should I give to the type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although in SimpleLineSymbol has property "width", for visualVariable you should use "size". type of the visualVariables should be size and in stops also use size. Make sure to not specify width for SimpleLineSymbol, as that will be the default line width and overwrites visualVariables. See the following example:

```
    var linkRenderer = new SimpleRenderer({
      symbol: new SimpleLineSymbol({cap: "round"}),
      visualVariables: [{
            type: "size",
            field: "Pr1",
            stops: [
                {value: 80,size: 1},
                {value: 160,size: 5}
            ]
      },{
           type: "color",
            field: "Pr2",
            stops: [
                {value: 3,color: "#f7fcb9"},//badbb6
                {value: 6,color: "#31a354"}//30a86a,217f4e
            ]
      }]
    });
```